# Не может найти файл, в чем причина?

Tags: python

[image: код]

при запуске выдает ошибку
FileNotFoundError: No file 'images/gun.png' found in working directory 'C:\Users\user'.
я переименовывал и указывал полный путь, не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: а где вы полный путь указываете? Привели бы сюда код, заодно еще раз проверьте, что по полному пути реально есть файл

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перед путем поставить символ `r`
Например
`pygame.image.load(r'path')`

Comment: спасибо, но почему это решило?

Comment: В строке есть такие функции как \n - перенос новой строки, \t - табуляция и т.д. а r эти функции так скажем удаляет, например у вас строка "dir/main.py", python это видит как "dirmain.py", Это можна пофиксить и без r а таким способом "dir//main.py", (Если что то / в строке позволяет дописовать строку в новой строке как `"Hello \  (Типа новая строка (ниже)), world!"` Да сложно но с опытом вы поймете!